# Why can't I get parameters using POST method in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here's what I'm trying using ajax:

```
var x="";
var xxx= setTimeout(myFunc, 7000);
function myFunc(){
    x=document.forms["form1"]["image"].value;
    if(x!=""){
    var xhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
        var z= xhttp.responseText;
        alert(z);
        }
    };
       xhttp.open("POST", "test.php", true);
       xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xhttp.send("url="+x);
    }
}
```

**Here's test.php:**

```
<?php
$a= $_POST["url"];
echo $a;
?>
```

But the **alert(z)** shows some HTML document, not the **URL**. What wrong I'm doing? How can I correct it and get parameters from ajax?

Comment: What is the "some HTML document" you are getting?

Comment: What does it show exactly? Perhaps it is an html-formatted error message...

Comment: I advise you to use a Javascript library to overcome browser specific issues with Ajax, by the way. Something like jQuery or dojo.

Comment: Yes it was an error message. I tried  to read it fully. I wrote something wrong in test.php that I hadn't posted here in details.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following corrections to your js part and `test.php` file:

- js part:

  ```
  ...
  var params = "url="+ encodeURIComponenet(x);
  xhttp.open("POST", "test.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
  xhttp.send(params);
  ```
- **test.php**

  ```
  <?php
      if (isset($_POST["url"]) && !empty($_POST["url"])) {
          $a = $_POST["url"];
          echo $a;
      }

  ?>
  ```